# How to use Static IP address for Browsing

Tags: vpn, static-ip

In order for me to access our client's website, I need to have a static IP Address whitelisted to their server. My idea is to buy Static IP from a provider, but I am not sure if it can be attached to a Browser so that their server can detect my whitelisted IP. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot buy a static IP address from any provider unfortunately, it isn't that straightforward.

Having the right to use an IP address is one thing, but having that IP address routed to your internet service is another.  It isn't a case of it just being applied to your network interface and having it work, because nothing else on the internet would know it is there.  It needs to be routed, which means that the internet is "told" how to get to it.

Usually, your internet provider is the best place to get an IP address - if they don't provide this service, then you can look for an alternative provider.  They will have ranges of IP addresses that are already routed to their infrastructure, and they can route individual addresses to individual services.

Often, once you buy an IP address, you don't need to do anything more - your provider will apply the IP address to you interface in the same way it does now - automatically.  It will just use the same IP each time rather than a random one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have home broadband connection, you need to configure your home broadband equipment with the static IP address that you obtain from the your provider.

If your broadband equipment is supplied by your provider and administered by them then they will do that for you.  If not you need to consult the user manual of your broadband router, to learn how to configure the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

From the tags and your post I deduct that you want to use an SSLVPN connection via browser, and in order to authenticate you need a static public IP address which you can have whitelisted at the other end.

What hasn't been answered yet is how you would attach a static IP to your browser.
Let's assume you have negotiated with your ISP to change your contract to obtain a static public IP address, be it either a real static address or a dynamically assigned address which never changes (both cases are common). Then your **whole network** will use this public static IP address. *Each computer*, PC, Mac, tablet which is attached to your home network (by cable or WiFi) will use it, and *each application* on these devices. One of those applications is your browser, and so you can get authenticated for your VPN connection.